# load google maps in a fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

hello everyone I'm just learning to use googlemaps and I have a problem. I want to add maps in a fragment. My code is:

```
public class MapsLine  extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
   
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps_line, container, false);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);  //use SuppoprtMapFragment for using in fragment instead of activity  MapFragment = activity   SupportMapFragment = fragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

                mMap.clear(); //clear old markers

                CameraPosition googlePlex = CameraPosition.builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(37.4219999,-122.0862462))
                        .zoom(10)
                        .bearing(0)
                        .tilt(45)
                        .build();

                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(googlePlex), 10000, null);

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(37.4219999, -122.0862462))
                        .title("Spider Man"));
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(37.4629101,-122.2449094))
                        .title("Iron Man")
                        .snippet("His Talent : Plenty of money"));

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(37.3092293,-122.1136845))
                        .title("Captain America"));
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    private BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptorFromVector(Context context, int vectorResId) {
        Drawable vectorDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, vectorResId);
        vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

mapsline_fragment-xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsLine">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.polygons.PolyActivity" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I added to the manifest:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="my key" ></meta-data>
```

i added to build.grabdle(livel app):
  `implementation 'com.google.android.gms: play-services-maps: 18.0.2'`
Now when the MapsLine fragment starts, it shows me a gray screen and doesn't show me google maps, it's like it can't load the map. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Check if you are using the correct API key and secondly if the location permission is given or not.

Comment: +1 for the (runtime) location permissions. Also is the onMapReady ever called? Have you checked your logs for any errors and warnings?

Comment: I discovered the problem, I was using the wrong key.

Comment: I have a question, what's the difference between Maps SDK for Android and other APIs? The problem is that I had generated a key on the Geolocation API, instead of the Maps SDK. What is the difference between one and the other?